# How to redirect subfolder/index.php to subfolder/

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

Hope, you understand my issue:

My website is in html/php and I am facing a small issue.

I am using htaccess as under for root index.php file :

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ / [L,R=301]
```

But I have sub-folders as well, like www.example.com/sub-folder/ 
and my sub-folders does not have any .htaccess file

Now, when I visit the website, www.example.com/index.php its redirects to www.example.com which is perfectly fine and what i need.

But, when I visit >> www.example.com/sub-folder/index.php
It should redirect to >> www.example.com/sub-folder/

But nothing working. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

To redirect /subfolder/index.php to /subfolder/ ,You can use :

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /subfolder/index\.php
RewriteRule ^subfolder/index\.php$ /subfolder/ [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this generic rule to remove `index.php` from anywhere in your site.

```
RewriteEngine On

# remove index.php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)index\.php$ /$1 [L,R=302,NC,NE]
```